# Git - rebase future branch

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I have this

```
* 4b874fe - (origin/create_testing_main)
|           Adding main.py for testing. 
| * 6684012 - (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
|/            Change all names to CamelCase. 
* fd1514b - add basic classes. 
* 04a58c6 - initial commit.
```

And I want to add CamelCase commit to future branch.

Somethink like this:

```
* 4b874fe - (origin/create_testing_main)
|           Adding main.py for testing. 
* 6684012 - (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
|            Change all names to CamelCase. 
* fd1514b - add basic classes. 
* 04a58c6 - initial commit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**it is not safe**

```
git checkout create_testing_main
git rebase master
```

and I check `git log` but there is somethig wird

but after `git push -f` it is like I want.